# i want to save my table data in mysql database through jsp

Tags: javascript, java, css

I am working on **jsp** with eclipse IDE. My project is based on an employee time management system. So I need to save how many hours an employee works daily along with the corresponding project name. If my table contains one record it takes the data and saves it properly. But my code is not working on multiple records. It takes only one record. But my requirement is to save multiple records in a table. Please tell me how to do this right.

```
**my form(user.php)**
<form method="post" action="addhours.jsp">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Project</th>
                <th><input type="text" name="date" value="<%=d.format(cal.getTime())%>" readonly></th>
                <th><input type="text" name="date" value="<%=d.format(cal2.getTime())%>" readonly></th>
                <th><input type="text" name="date" value="<%=d.format(cal3.getTime())%>" readonly></th>
                <th><input type="text" name="date" value="<%=d.format(cal4.getTime())%>" readonly></th>
                <th><input type="text" name="date" value="<%=d.format(cal5.getTime())%>" readonly></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% while (rs.next()) { %>
            <tr>  
                <th><input type="text" name="project_name" value="<% out.println(rs.getString("project_name")); %>" readonly></th>
                <td> 
                    <input type="text" name="day1" class="form-control">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% } %> 
        </tbody>        
    </table>
    <div class="panel-heading no-collapse text-center" style="font-size:14px">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
</form>


**code to save the data(addhours.php)**
<%
String project_id = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root",""); 
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String hours = request.getParameter("day1");
String userid = (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
String project_name = request.getParameter("project_name"); 
out.println(project_name);
String date = request.getParameter("date"); 

session.setAttribute("hours", hours);
out.println(hours);

ResultSet rs;
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from project_task where project_name = '"+project_name+"'");
if (rs.next())
    project_id=rs.getString("project_id");

if (hours != null && hours != "") {
    int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into workhours(userid,hours,project_id,date) values ('"+userid+"','"+hours+"','"+project_id+"','"+date+"')"); 
    out.println("saved");
}
%>
```

Comment: What do you expect when your `project_name` and `day1` fields all have the same name?

Comment: i am expecting that the date field i.e day1 will be saved along with related table heading data i.e project_name should save.only first record is saved but it is not taking the data from second record

Comment: You'll have to make arrays for the fields inside your while-loop. Example: `name="project_name[]"` - look at this: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-arrays-with-html-form-inputs

Answer (score 0):

Use `while loop` instead of `if` statement

```
rs=st.executeQuery("select * from project_task where    project_name='"+project_name+"'");
while(rs.next())
project_id=rs.getString("project_id");
if(hours!=null && hours!=""){
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into workhours(userid,hours,project_id,date) values ('"+userid+"','"+hours+"','"+project_id+"','"+date+"')"); 
        out.println("saved");
    }
```

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Comment: This indicate that `ResultSet` is closed and you are again executing your query